# On exceptions, get a interactive shell in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wonder if we can have in `Rails` an interactive shell when exceptions occurs accessible directly in the browser (so interacting with server via `javascript`)

I love this functionality bring up by `Werkzeug`. Examples of the `Werkzeug` Debugger :

- http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/#enabling-the-debugger
- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode

It can be great if we can do the same in `Rails`. Do you know some ways to archive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch all exceptions in ApplicationController and do whatever you want, like start a breakpoint.

```
if Rails.env.development?
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :fire_up_debugger
end

private
  def fire_up_debugger(e)
    print "An exception has happened: #{e.message}\n\n#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
    debugger # or binding.pry if you use pry
  end
```

Comment: I just realized you want an interactive shell in the browser, not the command line... well, maybe my answer will get you part of the way there :-D

Comment: Yeah I will try to implement it when I have free time, seems no easy! :) funny that nobody have done this.